# Excel string to date format

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I tried to convert string date value with format cell option but I failed. Tried search over and over again on web but didnt get better solution.

I want to convert following

> 23rd July 2015

to date format like

> 23/07/2015

Comment: You can change format of number values through cell formatting, but you can't convey text to date this way. Try to use `DATEVALUE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula to convert text to date:

`=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-5)&"1"),LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-3))`

where `A1` is your original string.