# Converting a date from mm/dd/yyyy to its numerical value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am getting data from a reporting tool. The report contains `Date` and `User` columns (in that order). The tool returns dates in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Excel does not convert the imported data to a numerical date; it is stored as a text value (the raw data from the reporting tool is aligned to the left instead of to the right).

I need to concatenate `User` and the numeric date value (in that order).  Using the raw imported data produces a result in the form `userAmm/dd/yyyy` instead of the needed format like `userA42379`.  The concatenation of date as an unformatted numeric value only happens correctly if the **raw data** is in dd/mm/yyyy format (otherwise the input data is not interpreted as a date).

I tried to convert the dates from mm/dd/yyyy format to dd/mm/yyyy format using `MID`/`LEFT`/`RIGHT` and the number formatting in Excel but that didn't work. The date still appears in mm/dd/yyyy format when concatenated with another cell with text in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Provide examples of the data you are using, and the formulas you are using.  Most likely you are not handling your data (be it text or "real dates") properly, but since you have chosen to not share either the data or the formulas with us, we'd only be guessing as to what your problem is. Simplest would be to upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem to some public sharing site, and post a link here.

Comment: Dates are stored as numbers.  So you can use one of the relevant information functions to determine if a value is text or numeric.

Comment: or just reformat the date cell as number. If it appears as a number then it's date format, otherwise it's simple text

Comment: Note to readers and answerers: This question was originally very unclear (an X Y problem).  We have cleaned up extensive discussion threads in comments, and the question has been rewritten based on what was learned in the discussions and from a sample worksheet shared elsewhere.  It now reflects the actual intentions of the question.  Some of the current answers may now appear wrong or irrelevant based on the rewrite.  Apologies to those answerers; stuff happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel string to date format](https://superuser.com/questions/976467/excel-string-to-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution that will work for *any* <sup>*</sup> date format beginning with a month, irrespective of whether it is stored as a text value or a proper datetime (serial date) value:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `D2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the column:

```dart
=TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(C2),C2,DATE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"/","  "),4),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"/","  "),3),MID(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"/","  "),4,3))),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

The result is stored as a text value. If a serial date value is required, then simply omit the `TEXT()` function and set the number format of the cell to `dd/mm/yyyy`

---

If the source date format is always `mm/dd/yyyy` then the formula simplifies to the following:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

```dart
=TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(C2),C2,DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),LEFT(C2,2),MID(C2,4,2))),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

---

For your specific case where you generate a concatenated `UserDate` column, just omit the `TEXT()` function:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

```dart
="UserName"&IF(ISNUMBER(C2),C2,DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),LEFT(C2,2),MID(C2,4,2)))
```

If the date is always stored as a text value, the formula can be simplified further:

```dart
="UserName"&DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),LEFT(C2,2),MID(C2,4,2))
```

Comment: Quite clever to use `SUBSTITUTE()` with double space to prepare any format of month, day and year to fit the extracting code.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks. Yeah, I thought it would be good to create a general formula. The double space idea was the first one I tried, and it worked splendidly!

Answer (score 0):

You said the report contains `Date` and `User` columns (in that order).

You also said the tool returns dates in **text format** in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy`.  Let's say in that case you have the folowing:

[image]

You need to concatenate `User` and `Date` value (in that order).  This is what we are going to do in cell `C2`

Now I am confused as to which way you wish the concatenated date format to be.  Do you want it in `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` do you want the date code to give an output such as `userA 42379`?

I will cover all three.

### For concatenating whilst maintaining the date format (`mm/dd/yyyy`), use the following formula

```
=B2&" "&A2
```

[image]

The `&" "&` in the middle adds the space in between.

### For concatenating the date in the format (`dd/mm/yyyy`), use the following formula

```
=B2&" "&MID(A2,4,2)&"/"&LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2,4)
```

[image]

### For concatenating the date code such as `42379`, use the following formula

```
=B2&" "&DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,4,2))
```

[image]

Comment: So, in the end you've ended up with exactly the same formula as mine. At least you know that it'll work then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Over thinking it.  Just multiply the date cell by 1 to have it recognized as a number

=CONCATENATE(B2,A2*1)

Answer (score -1):

Select dates in range either manually or using the find option, format, and date then something like, astrick/astrick/2018.

Change the format of all that are found to `dd/mm/yyyy`, if that's what you wanted.

I tried the `=CONCATENATE` and it gaves me the same numerical value with `dd/mm/yy` and `mm/dd/yy` so changing the format has no impact numerically.

To get it to show up in date format instead of numerical in the `Concatenate` function I had to enter `"&TEXT(A4,"mm/dd/yy")` with `A4` being the test location for my date. This allowed it to show something like The date in `A4` is `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
Sample

Row A1 Japan
    A2 June
    A3 02/07/2018
```

`=CONCATENATE("The date in ", A1, " is ", ""&TEXT(A3,"mm/dd/yy"), " currently.")`

Output = `The date in Japan is 07/02/18 currently`.

Hope this helps. I think it's what your looking for.

Comment: No sorry.........

Answer (score -2):

*Check the Screen Shot:*

[image]

In Cell M1 Write this formula, will convert date from MM/DD/YYYY format to DD/MM/YYYY.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(K1),TEXT(K1,"DD/MM/YYYY"),K1)
```

**Edited: Date in MM/DD/YYYY format as Text to Date in DD/MM/YYYY format.**

[image]

you can use this formula: `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(A97),"dd/mm/YYYY")`

**Note,** *adjust the cell address in both the formulas according to your need.*

Comment: Hi, it's still the same. Also I noticed that the raw data from the reporting tool is aligned to the left instead of to the right

Comment: @Astrid22, it seems dates are formatted as Text since aligned to left. Even though this formula will convert it to DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: What is wrong with the **edited formula** can someone just write the mistake?

Comment: @Astrid22, just check the edited part of my answer converting Date as Text from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: @fixer1234, If Date is a text value then this can be used to convert it into desire Date format, **=TEXT(- -A3,"DD/MM/YYYY")**

Comment: @fixer1234, tell me Plz how can I apply code effect { } Ctrl +K to formula while commenting ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79723/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-fixer1234).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for valuable feedback, I'll try to fix it soon.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure how this will work for others but this is what worked for me.

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(MID($Q4,4,2)&"/"&LEFT($Q4,2)&"/"&RIGHT($Q4,4)),"")
```